Issue installing google-cloud-logging with pipenv
The command
pipenv install google-cloud-logging
fails. I got the following errors:
Locking Failed!
c:\users\duytr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py:14: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
  import pkg_resources
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "c:\users\duytr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py", line 741, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, dev)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "c:\users\duytr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py", line 702, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "c:\users\duytr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py", line 684, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "c:\users\duytr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 1397, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(        
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "c:\users\duytr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 1110, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "c:\users\duytr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 835, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.   
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,<6.0.0.dev0,<6.0.0dev,<6.0dev,>=3.19.0,>=3.19.5,>=3.20.2,>=5.26.1 (from google-cloud-logging==3.11.0->-r C:\Users\duytr\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv6l6f5h3crequirements\pipenv-cb00soun-constraints.txt (line 2))
Tried: 2.0.3, 2.3.0, 2.4.1, 2.5.0, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.0.post1, 3.1.0.post1, 3.2.0, 3.2.0, 3.3.0, 3.4.0, 3.4.0, 3.5.0.post1, 3.5.0.post1, 3.5.1, 3.5.1, 3.5.2, 3.5.2, 3.5.2.post1, 3.5.2.post1, 3.6.0, 3.6.0, 3.6.1, 3.6.1, 3.7.0, 3.7.0, 3.7.1, 3.7.1, 3.8.0, 3.8.0, 3.9.0, 3.9.0, 3.9.1, 3.9.1, 3.9.2, 3.9.2, 3.10.0, 3.10.0, 3.11.0, 3.11.0, 3.11.1, 3.11.1, 3.11.2, 3.11.2, 3.11.3, 3.11.3, 3.12.2, 3.12.2, 3.12.4, 3.12.4, 3.13.0, 3.13.0, 3.14.0, 3.14.0, 3.15.0, 3.15.0, 3.15.1, 3.15.1, 3.15.2, 3.15.2, 3.15.3, 3.15.3, 3.15.4, 3.15.4, 3.15.5, 3.15.5, 3.15.6, 3.15.6, 3.15.7, 3.15.7, 3.15.8, 3.15.8, 3.16.0, 3.16.0, 3.17.0, 3.17.0, 3.17.1, 3.17.1, 3.17.2, 3.17.2, 3.17.3, 3.17.3, 3.18.0, 3.18.0, 3.18.1, 3.18.1, 3.18.3, 3.18.3, 3.19.0, 3.19.0, 3.19.1, 3.19.1, 3.19.2, 3.19.2, 3.19.3, 3.19.3, 3.19.3, 3.19.4, 3.19.4, 3.19.4, 3.19.5, 3.19.5, 3.19.5, 3.19.6, 3.19.6, 3.19.6, 3.20.0, 3.20.0, 3.20.0, 3.20.1, 3.20.1, 3.20.1, 3.20.2, 3.20.2, 3.20.2, 3.20.3, 3.20.3, 3.20.3, 4.21.0, 4.21.0, 4.21.0, 4.21.0, 4.21.1, 4.21.1, 4.21.1, 4.21.1, 4.21.2, 4.21.2, 4.21.2, 4.21.2, 4.21.3, 4.21.3, 4.21.3, 4.21.3, 4.21.4, 4.21.4, 4.21.4, 4.21.4, 4.21.5, 4.21.5, 4.21.5, 4.21.5, 4.21.6, 4.21.6, 4.21.6, 4.21.6, 4.21.7, 4.21.7, 4.21.7, 4.21.7, 4.21.8, 4.21.8, 4.21.8, 4.21.8, 4.21.9, 4.21.9, 4.21.9, 4.21.9, 4.21.10, 4.21.10, 4.21.10, 4.21.10, 4.21.11, 4.21.11, 4.21.11, 4.21.11, 4.21.12, 4.21.12, 4.21.12, 4.21.12, 4.22.0, 4.22.0, 4.22.0, 4.22.1, 4.22.1, 4.22.1, 4.22.3, 4.22.3, 4.22.3, 4.22.4, 4.22.4, 4.22.4, 4.22.5, 4.22.5, 4.22.5, 4.23.0, 4.23.0, 4.23.0, 4.23.1, 4.23.1, 4.23.1, 4.23.2, 4.23.2, 4.23.2, 4.23.3, 4.23.3, 4.23.3, 4.23.4, 4.23.4, 4.23.4, 4.24.0, 4.24.0, 4.24.0, 4.24.1, 4.24.1, 4.24.1, 4.24.2, 4.24.2, 4.24.2, 4.24.3, 4.24.3, 4.24.3, 4.24.4, 4.24.4, 4.24.4, 4.25.0, 4.25.0, 4.25.0, 4.25.1, 4.25.1, 4.25.1, 4.25.2, 4.25.2, 4.25.2, 4.25.3, 4.25.3, 4.25.3, 4.25.4, 4.25.4, 4.25.4, 5.26.0, 5.26.0, 5.26.0, 5.26.1, 5.26.1, 5.26.1, 5.27.0, 5.27.0, 5.27.0, 5.27.1, 5.27.1, 5.27.1, 5.27.2, 5.27.2, 5.27.2
Skipped pre-versions: 2.0.0b0, 3.0.0a2, 3.0.0a3, 3.0.0b1, 3.0.0b1.post1, 3.0.0b1.post2, 3.0.0b2, 3.0.0b2, 3.0.0b2.post1, 3.0.0b2.post1, 3.0.0b2.post2, 3.0.0b2.post2, 3.0.0b3, 3.0.0b4, 3.0.0b4, 3.2.0rc1, 3.2.0rc1, 3.2.0rc1.post1, 3.2.0rc1.post1, 3.2.0rc2, 3.2.0rc2, 3.7.0rc2, 3.7.0rc2, 3.7.0rc3, 3.7.0rc3, 3.8.0rc1, 3.8.0rc1, 3.9.0rc1, 3.9.0rc1, 3.10.0rc1, 3.10.0rc1, 3.11.0rc1, 3.11.0rc1, 3.11.0rc2, 3.11.0rc2, 3.13.0rc3, 3.13.0rc3, 3.14.0rc1, 3.14.0rc1, 3.14.0rc2, 3.14.0rc2, 3.14.0rc3, 3.14.0rc3, 3.15.0rc1, 3.15.0rc1, 3.15.0rc2, 3.15.0rc2, 3.16.0rc1, 3.16.0rc1, 3.16.0rc2, 3.16.0rc2, 3.17.0rc1, 3.17.0rc1, 3.17.0rc2, 3.17.0rc2, 3.18.0rc1, 3.18.0rc1, 3.18.0rc2, 3.18.0rc2, 3.19.0rc1, 3.19.0rc1, 3.19.0rc2, 3.19.0rc2, 3.20.0rc1, 3.20.0rc1, 3.20.0rc1, 3.20.0rc2, 3.20.0rc2, 3.20.0rc2, 3.20.1rc1, 3.20.1rc1, 3.20.1rc1, 4.0.0rc1, 4.0.0rc1, 4.0.0rc2, 4.0.0rc2, 4.21.0rc1, 4.21.0rc1, 4.21.0rc1, 4.21.0rc1, 4.21.0rc2, 4.21.0rc2, 4.21.0rc2, 4.21.0rc2, 4.22.0rc1, 4.22.0rc2, 4.22.0rc2, 4.22.0rc2, 4.22.0rc3, 4.22.0rc3, 4.22.0rc3, 4.23.0rc2, 4.23.0rc2, 4.23.0rc2, 4.23.0rc3, 4.23.0rc3, 4.23.0rc3, 4.24.0rc1, 4.24.0rc1, 4.24.0rc1, 4.24.0rc2, 4.24.0rc2, 4.24.0rc2, 4.24.0rc3, 4.24.0rc3, 4.24.0rc3, 4.25.0rc1, 4.25.0rc1, 4.25.0rc1, 4.25.0rc2, 4.25.0rc2, 4.25.0rc2, 5.26.0rc1, 5.26.0rc1, 5.26.0rc1, 5.26.0rc2, 5.26.0rc2, 5.26.0rc2, 5.26.0rc3, 5.26.0rc3, 5.26.0rc3, 5.27.0rc1, 5.27.0rc1, 5.27.0rc1, 5.27.0rc2, 5.27.0rc2, 5.27.0rc2, 5.27.0rc3, 5.27.0rc3, 5.27.0rc3, 5.28.0rc1, 5.28.0rc1, 5.28.0rc1
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies:
  protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5 (from google-cloud-logging==3.11.0->-r C:\Users\duytr\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv6l6f5h3crequirements\pipenv-cb00soun-constraints.txt (line 2))
  protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<6.0.0.dev0,>=3.19.5 (from google-api-core[grpc]==2.19.1->google-cloud-logging==3.11.0->-r C:\Users\duytr\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv6l6f5h3crequirements\pipenv-cb00soun-constraints.txt (line 2))
  protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5 (from google-cloud-audit-log==0.2.5->google-cloud-logging==3.11.0->-r C:\Users\duytr\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv6l6f5h3crequirements\pipenv-cb00soun-constraints.txt (line 2))
  protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<6.0.0.dev0,>=3.20.2 (from googleapis-common-protos[grpc]==1.63.2->grpc-google-iam-v1==0.13.1->google-cloud-logging==3.11.0->-r C:\Users\duytr\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv6l6f5h3crequirements\pipenv-cb00soun-constraints.txt (line 2))
  protobuf!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<6.0.0dev,>=3.20.2 (from google-cloud-appengine-logging==1.4.4->google-cloud-logging==3.11.0->-r C:\Users\duytr\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv6l6f5h3crequirements\pipenv-cb00soun-constraints.txt (line 2))
  protobuf!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<6.0.0dev,>=3.20.2 (from grpc-google-iam-v1==0.13.1->google-cloud-logging==3.11.0->-r C:\Users\duytr\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv6l6f5h3crequirements\pipenv-cb00soun-constraints.txt (line 2))
  protobuf<6.0.0dev,>=3.19.0 (from proto-plus==1.24.0->google-cloud-logging==3.11.0->-r C:\Users\duytr\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv6l6f5h3crequirements\pipenv-cb00soun-constraints.txt (line 2))
  protobuf<6.0dev,>=5.26.1 (from grpcio-status==1.65.1->google-api-core[grpc]==2.19.1->google-cloud-logging==3.11.0->-r C:\Users\duytr\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv6l6f5h3crequirements\pipenv-cb00soun-constraints.txt (line 2)) 

Here is my Pipfile:
Pipfile:
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
google-cloud-logging = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.10" ```

It seems to me like there is a dependency mismatch between grpcio-status and google-cloud-logging. The library grpcio-status requires protobuf >=5.26.1, but google-cloud-logging requires protobuf <5.0.0dev.

As per this open Github issue  you are correct that google-cloud-logging is having an ongoing issue supporting the protobuf 5.x versions. As they mention, a fix will be available after the rollout of the new version of google-cloud-logging library. So the compatibility issues might get resolved.
If you are looking for an alternative then you might have to downgrade the both google-cloud-logging and grpcio-status libraries that will support the common protobuf version.
Refer this open github PR request and open public issue to know updates of google-cloud-logging new version rollout.
If you want to raise an issue you can create a new Issue Tracker thread describing your issue. If you have paid support try to create a new support issue.

Thank you. Downgraded google-cloud-logging to 3.9.0 and grpcio-status to 1.62.0 and the issue is fixed now.
